# how to mail from node js from corporate user.Which service should I use?

Tags: node.js

Instead of gmail I have to use my corporate user mail id how should i do it

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
      user: 'example@gmail.com',
      pass: 'app password here'
    }
  });
transporter.sendMail(option, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

Comment: We can't tell you what protocols your corporate mail server uses to accept mail.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use Gmail for corporate use, it comes with lots of limits.

I suggest a good option: SendGrid (https://sendgrid.com), it is recommended by Google, even on Google Cloud as Google Cloud seems to block outgoing SMTP by default (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).

SendGrid support 2 methods for sending email, both are great, 100 mail / day for free:

- Through HTTP request
- Through SMTP

Answer (score 0):

Use [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/),
it also has its own npm package [@sendgrid/mail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail) to send mail

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `nodemailer` you can specify the host and port of your corporate mail provider with :

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: 'example@gmail.com',
      pass: 'app password here'
    }});
```

You can find more details on [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/).